# Was Nazareth a joke town?

Tags: john

Nathanael said ([John 1:46a](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%201:46a&version=NIV1984)):

> “Nazareth! Can anything good come from there?” Nathanael asked.

What was the reputation of Nazareth at the time? Was it considered a "joke town" to be made fun of?

Comment: Related: 'Was “No prophet ever came out of Galilee” sarcastic?'
http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/19010/was-no-prophet-ever-came-out-of-galilee-sarcastic/52159#52159

Comment: In the Talmud, Nazareth was neither Sadducee, or Pharisee... And, the Galilee heavily populated by Gentiles.   So, it is certain that Nazareth was looked down on - for those reasons alone.  Possibly answered in,  [John 7 - What about Galilee Could Account for Jesus' Teachings?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/27648/john-7-what-about-galilee-could-account-for-jesus-teachings).  Also closely related to: [Matthew 4 - How Should Galilee of the Nations be Interpreted?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/26343/matthew-4-how-should-galilee-of-the-nations-be-interpreted)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No solid source, but I always assumed Jerusalem Jews at the time thought of Galilee (and therefore Nazareth) Jews as hicks. It would be like suggesting the Savior would come from West Virginia or New Hampshire. The passage implies that Nathanael himself was from Galilee (perhaps, Bethsaida).  In that case, it would appear he considered Nazareth even more of a backwater, like [Texarkana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texarkana,_Texas).  (Some of my wife's relations are from that town and I get the feeling they make their unimportance a point of pride.)

As Affable Geek points out, there is no prior or contemporary (including Josephus) historical record of the town.  One must assume that Jesus' hometown was very small.

---

I did find some of Josephus' [description of Galilee](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/josephus/complete.iii.iv.iii.html):

> These two Galilees, of so great largeness, and encompassed with so many nations of foreigners, have been always able to make a strong resistance on all occasions of war; for the Galileans are inured to war from their infancy, and have been always very numerous; nor hath the country been ever destitute of men of courage, or wanted a numerous set of them; for their soil is universally rich and fruitful, and full of the plantations of trees of all sorts, insomuch that it invites the most slothful to take pains in its cultivation, by its fruitfulness; accordingly, it is all cultivated by its inhabitants, and no part of it lies idle. Moreover, the cities lie here very thick, and the very many villages there are here are every where so full of people, by the richness of their soil, that the very least of them contain above fifteen thousand inhabitants.

It should be noted that Josephus was part of a Jewish revolt in Galilee that was put down by Vespasian.  He had some reason to emphasize the importance of Galilee.  However, we might glean some of Nathanael's surprise that anyone would claim the Messiah came from a village in that region since it was populated by foreigners (i.e. gentiles) and known more for its farming and fighting than its learning and virtue.

Comment: Even today that seems to be the case.  I spent time in Israel and when I told friends I was going to Nazareth, their comment was, "Oh, yeah, what's his name spent time up there, didn't he."  Although Nazareth is within Israel, it is an Arab and not a Jewish town.  The first thing one sees there getting off the bus from Haifa is a huge mosque.  The non-Jewishness of Nazareth and of Galilee in general is a major frustration to Zionists, who have set up all-Jewish sister cities such as Nazareth-Ilit in order to erase Arab influence, but these efforts haven't succeeded.

Comment: @John Ericson Just added one comma, an unnecessary one, you will not even guess or notice. The reason is that I have accidentally pushed down-vote arrow, and it could be removed only after editing by change to up-vote. A good, informative answer.

Comment: @LevanGigineishvili: No problem. Funny thing: I don't recall writing it. ;-)

Comment: Then you should be content that in doing, sorry, writing good, your right hand forgets what your left does ;)

Answer (score 5):

According to the Anchor Yale Dictionary, there is no extra-biblical mention of Nazereth, prior to 300 AD. As such, the conjecture is that Nazereth was just a minor village in the proximity of Sepphoris, the town Josephus called "the crown jewel of the Galilee."

The much larger town of Sepphoris was only a few kilometers away, and is more likely to have been where Joseph and Jesus would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Nazareth could be considered slightly better than the Samaritians, because being so close to the Greek civilizations, and like Peter being recognized by his slang, individuals could be influenced by the Greeks in many ways, thus rendering them of a lower class of people.

Comment: Can you support this hypothesis with references?